# Regarding Oracle query functional behaviour

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE ak_temp
(
  misc_1 varchar2(4000),
  misc_2 varchar2(4000),
  time_of_insert timestamp  
);
```

Query 1(Original) :

```
select * 
  from ak_temp 
 where misc_1 in('ankush') 
    or misc_2 in('ankush')
```

Query 2 :

```
select * 
  from ak_temp 
 where 'ankush' in (misc_1,misc_2)
```

Hi, I have somewhat similar problem with the queries, i want to avoid Query 1 since the cost in our live environment is coming bit on higher side so i have figured out Query 2 with less cost, are these both functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

The two are functionally equivalent and should produce the same query plan, so one should not have a performance advantage over the other (or any such advantage would be miniscule).  Oracle might be smart enough to take advantage of two indexes, one on `ak_temp(misc_1)` and one on `ak_temp(misc_2)`.

However, you might also consider:

```
select t.* 
from ak_temp t
where misc_1 = 'ankush'
union
select t.*
from ak_temp t
where misc_2 = 'ankush';
```

This version will definitely take advantage of indexes, but the `union` can slow things down if many rows match the two conditions.

EDIT:

To avoid the `union`, you can do:

```
select t.* 
from ak_temp t
where misc_1 = 'ankush'
union all
select t.*
from ak_temp t
where misc_2 = 'ankush' and (misc_1 <> 'ankush' and misc_1 is not null);  -- or use `lnnvl()`
```

Comment: `Union` can be avoided and can be repaced with `UNION ALL` with the help of [LNNVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions078.htm) function used in the bottom branch of the query - that is `where misc_2 = 'ankush' AND LNNVL( misc_1 = 'ankush' )`. See this link for more details: [Oracle - OR Expansion](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/or_expansion_transformation). BTW - `union` will only work on the assumption that the table doesn't contain duplicate rows, otherwise it is not equivalent to the oryginal query and it will give wrong results.